# Setting up ZUUL gateway between micro services

Tags: netflix-zuul

Following services are running

```
Eureka server
ZUUL gateway (api-gateway)
User service (user-service)
Plan service (plan-service)
```

User service will communicate to Plan service via ZUUL using "OpenFeign" for invocation.

"User service" has the the following "PlanService" open feign client

```
@FeignClient(name = "api-gateway")
@RibbonClient(name = "plan-service")
public interface PlanServiceFeign {
 @GetMapping("/plan-service/plandetails/{userId}")
 PlanDetails getPlanDetails(@PathVariable("userId") String userId);
}
```

In the logs following URL is getting fired to API gateway, but zuul is not navigating to the "plan-service" micro setvice

GET http://api-gateway/plan-service/plandetails/12345

Am I missing any other configuration for setting up ZUUL between micro services communication

Answer (score 2):

There is a configuration, you should configure in an application.properties file or application.yaml file.

If you used an application.yaml file please configure like this.

```
zuul:
  routes:
    plan:
      path: /plandetails/**
      serviceId: plan-service
```

If you used an application.properties file Please configure like this.

```
zuul.routes.plan-service.path = /plandetails/**
```

Answer (score 0):

Fixed by adding routing settings to the application.properties

```
zuul.routes.<service-registry-name>.path=/<service-mapping>/*
```